# Javascript Safari Div background image not visible

Tags: javascript, html, browser, safari

If a Div has textContent and a background image, the text and the image are visible in all browsers.

But if the textContent is removed (eg. by removing the textContent line from the code below), the image is still visible (as desired) in Chrome and Firefox (windows), but not in Safari (iphone) - the screen is completely blank.

```
<body>
<script>
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.style="width:100px; height:10px;";
myDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('c.jpg')";
myDiv.textContent='a';
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
</script>
</body>
```

Is there any way to keep the div background image visible without textContent?

Demo:

with text- image visible on Chrome and iPhone:

https://jsfiddle.net/youngt917/t5ycpoj0/

without text- image visible on Chrome, not on iPhone:

https://jsfiddle.net/youngt917/3wd38b9t/

Answer (score 0):

instead of removing the textContent line, just set it to be empty

```
myDiv.textContent='';
```